casting rhythmbox to chromecast
How can I stream music (mp3 files) from rhythmbox to a Chromeast?
I'm using Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS. I have installed mkchromecast, but it did not work.

Does it have to be rhythmbox? I think vlc can cast, can't you use that?

VLC is a good alternative, but I was wondering if Rhythmbox could do the same
